# Работа с сокетами Ubuntu + nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, битрикс, сокеты

Доброго дня!

Пытаюсь разобраться с оптимизацией сервера и работы Битрикс на нем. В Битриксе есть тест конфигурации системы, в нем он проверяет некоторые параметры сервера и конфигурацию PHP. В результате прохождения теста он ругается на работу с сокетами: «Ошибка! Не работает». Что необходимо проверить, донастроить в конфигах?

Сама система дает такие комментарии к этой ошибке:

> Осуществляется сетевое подключение с веб-сервера к самому себе. Это
>   необходимо чтобы проверить работу сетевых функций, а также требуется
>   для ряда последующих тестов.
>
> Обычно проблема возникает, если подключение запрещено фаерволом,
>   доступ к административной части запрещен по IP или для входа на сайт
>   требуется HTTP/NTLM авторизация.

Тест происходит следующим образом. В браузере из под админа запускается скрипт, которые делает все проверки.

Судя по всему, эта функция отвечает за данную проверку.

```
function check_socket()
{
    $strRequest = "GET "."/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?test_type=socket_test&unique_id=".checker_get_unique_id()." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $strRequest.= "Host: ".$this->host."\r\n";
    $strRequest.= "\r\n";

    $retVal = false;

    if ($res = $this->ConnectToHost())
        $retVal = IsHttpResponseSuccess($res, $strRequest);

    if (!$retVal)
        $this->arTestVars['check_socket_fail'] = 1;
    return $retVal;
}
```

**UPD: Логи этой проверки самого Битрикса**:

> ```
> 2015-Aug-08 16:58:45 Работа с сокетами (check_socket): Fail
> Connection to example.ru:80 Success
> == Request ==
> GET /bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?test_type=socket_test&unique_id=c14dc6ee0355801288c2fa1175e31c70 HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.ru
>
>
> == Response ==
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
> Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 13:58:45 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 177
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> == Body ==
> <html>
> <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
> </body>
> </html>
>
> ==========
> ```

Comment: наверняка к этой программе прилагается справка, в которой написано, что на самом деле означают эти загадочные слова: «ошибка! не работает».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, конкретных инструкций не дается. Есть такая заметка: Осуществляется сетевое подключение с веб-сервера к самому себе. | Обычно проблема возникает, если подключение запрещено фаерволом, доступ к административной части запрещен по IP или для входа на сайт требуется HTTP/NTLM авторизация.

Comment: инструкции местные специалисты и сами смогут дать. если знать, что именно проверяется. «сетевое подключение веб-сервера к самому себе» — для меня лично Звучит не менее загадочно, чем «ошибка! не работает». если вы можете в коде найти (если он не обфусцирован, конечно), что именно делает эта часть «теста конфигурации», то приложите, пожалуйста, его фрагмент к вопросу. тогда можно будет и рекомендации дать по устранению «ошибки».

Comment: если попытаться «ткнуть пальцем в небо», то: как вы запускаете этот тест? через браузер с другого компьютера? или с этого же самого? что именно вы вводите в адресной строке для «попадания» на страницу теста? на какой именно адрес ведёт ссылка «начать тест» (или как она там называется)?

Comment: лучше всего, если запрашиваемую в комментариях информацию вы будете добавлять в текст вопроса (нажав кнопку [edit]), а в комментарии лишь писать что-нибудь вроде: «обновил вопрос» — чтобы ваш собеседник получил уведомление.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо. Удалось найти функцию, которая отвечает за проверку. Добавил ее в вопрос.

Comment: отлично! осталось убедиться лишь в том, что: 1. в переменной `$this->host` на момент обращения к ней содержится правильное доменное имя. 2. что команда `curl -I 'http://это.самое.доменное.имя/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?test_type=socket_test&unique_id=12345'`, выполненная на машине, где работает ваш http-сервер, либо завершается с ошибкой, либо выдаёт не 200-й http-код ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, докопался до логов, которые пишет скрипт при проверки. Судя по ним: пункт 1 - доменное имя правильное, пункт 2 все ок, при открытии этого url с параметрами, в браузере выводится SUCCESS, а сервер возвращает ответ 200. Кусок лог файла дописал в вопрос.

Comment: тогда не стоит и обращать внимания на эту проверку. ведь всё отлично работает. логично будет (если вдруг у вас появится желание) послать баг-репорт разработчикам.

Comment: аналогичная проблема. Но есть подозрение, что данная ошибка может частично мешать редактированию компонентов системы bitrix(но это не точно.... привет из 2017 :-) )

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.ru #указываем то имя домена, с которого делали проверку
```